# Load JSON from a URL with an invalid certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm doing an app that requests a json from an URL to display data. Everything was working fine but recently the API turned to https but the certificate is invalid. So whenever I try to load from the URL I get:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

I tried adding

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

to my .plist (which was already here since the API was http before)

I'm using SwiftyJSON and my code looks like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    json = JSON(data: getDataFromAPI("https://testaws.my_url.com/test"))
}

func getDataFromAPI(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData {
    return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!)!
}
```

I also tried using NSURLConnection, adding the two connection methods but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's time for you to use another method to retreive the json like using Alamofire library that has an integration with SwiftyJSON. In the README there is a section that let you to customize the trust policy of certificates (ref: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#security )

Comment: The question was "how to load a json with an invalid certificate on the server". He knows that certificate is invalid so i think the solution (for testing as the url suggested) should be disable the security check for the url and use a library which manages better situation and not buy a SSL from an authority only for testing.

Comment: it took me a bit of time to be at ease with Alamofire but eventually everything is working fine and looks better. So I think this was the solution somehow. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have go through same problem my solution might be help you please try it

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

Above error meaning that your SSL certificate is expired or either Your device time is not set properly.

**1)Check weather your SSL certificate expired.**

**2)Check device time where you build the application.**